# How do I show a dialpad activity

Tags: android, android-layout, resources

I need to show a dialpad interface to the user to he can "dial" (actually he will just send te DTMF tones), a sequence of numbers.
This activity must provide a way to get every number the user "dials";
and get the time interval between the user selections.

Is there any android-layout resource to show a dialpad, or I need to design my own dialpad?

Answer (score 1):

here is the code so that you can access the build in dialpad of your android phone.In tha layout you have to register 1 button so that when you clicked that button dial-pad comes up...

```java
public class DialerActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialphone();
            }
        });

        }
    private void dialphone(){
        try{

        Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        startActivity(dialIntent);
        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("call failed", "failed", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in/platform layout resource that provides a dialpad. What's probably the easiest thing to do is use the standard Contacts app's layout as seen at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/gingerbread-release/res/layout-finger/dialpad.xml

Let me know if that helps.